# How can I control an android application with a Bluetooth device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm attempting to create an android application that is controlled by a Bluetooth device. Most documentation available has tutorials on how to control a Bluetooth device from an application, but not the other way around. How can I control an application without using the Bluetooth device as a keyboard? I can not replace the device's on-screen keyboard.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "control an application"?

Comment: Pair a Bluetooth device with an Android phone, press a button on said device, and have a sister application that I can program to respond to the button presses on the Bluetooth device- preferably while not having the Bluetooth device act as a keyboard. I'm trying to make a sort of 'life alert' for millennials,  type application- quite similar to Google's trusted contacts app that can be paired with a custom made Bluetooth device